# Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Tags: typescript, electron

I am using typescript in electron application. Typescript shows

> Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Here is the code. So what should I do ?

```js
ipcRenderer.on('download-progress', function (event, progressInfo: ProgressInfo) {
    document.getElementById('pbs_' + progressInfo.id).style.width = progressInfo.percent + "%";
    document.getElementById('pts_' + progressInfo.id).innerHTML = progressInfo.percent + "%";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation shows, [`ipcRenderer.on`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener) takes a `event` as second argument which you specified correctly. You can see the documentation on the event Object [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#objet-event).

So if you want to type it completely, assuming you have `Electron` imported already, `event` is of type `Electron.Event` :

```js
ipcRenderer.on('download-progress', function (event: Electron.Event, progressInfo: ProgressInfo) {
    document.getElementById('pbs_' + progressInfo.id).style.width = progressInfo.percent + "%";
    document.getElementById('pts_' + progressInfo.id).innerHTML = progressInfo.percent + "%";
});
```

For reference, here is the generic Electron.Event's type definition :

```js
interface Event extends GlobalEvent {
  preventDefault: () => void;
  sender: WebContents;
  returnValue: any;
  ctrlKey?: boolean;
  metaKey?: boolean;
  shiftKey?: boolean;
  altKey?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Worked fine. But I have another question, why event.senderId not working? and event.sender.sendTo() is not working. what is the reason here.

Comment: Hmm, that's another problem. Did you try logging the whole `event` Object to see all the properties it has ?

Comment: yes, I have looked the property, there is no property name senderId. But this property exist in electron [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#eventsenderid)

Comment: Hm I don't know what could cause that except a different Electron version then